# Microsoft JDBC SQL Server Connection Problems

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, jdbc

I have followed tutorials and other questions and answers for connecting to Microsoft SQL Server using Java but have found them to be lacking when it comes to configuring the SQL Server for an eventual connect from a Java program. Currently I am unable to connect to it from Eclipse and would like to clarify a few points:

1. When creating a New Login for the Server what is the correct option to use, WINDOWS AUTHENTICATION or SQL SERVER AUTHENTICATION, by this I mean I would like to know which would be better to use when I eventually want to connect to it using Java?
2. Once I have created a new login and then create a new DataBase should the owner then be set to the same as the new login created above?
3. Then further to this is this the correct code to use when wanting to connect to the Database?

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
java.sql.Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;" + "databaseName=HELP" + "password=Help");
System.out.println("Connected to DataBase");
```

Comment: Your question doesnt make a lot of sense.  Are you having trouble with a java connection or with SSMS?  Recommending tutorials is off topic for SO if thats what youre asking.

Comment: Please post the exception you're getting.

Comment: @paqogomez My problem is that I can't connect to the SQL Server and I don't know where I am going wrong, if it is server side or Java side. Asking for a tutorial was a last resort as was posting a question. sorry for being off topic with that, I just want to get this sorted.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch updated with part of the Exception.

Comment: Add your user name and password (make sure it's been configured for access to SQL server). Don't post them here, but you need to authenticate to sql server - your exception "Login failed for user ''" is pretty clear. You might find [this](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/user-manual/quick_start.html#howtoconnect) helpful.

Comment: @paqogomez I have edited the question and hopefully provided a better one. How should the "On Hold" be removed. Thank you

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I have updated my question could you please offer any advice.

Comment: RE: details - Your latest edit is a step in the right direction, but you still need to add more detail. For example, what version and edition of SQL Server are you using? (SQL Server Express edition does not enable TCP/IP by default. It also does *not* use port 1433 by default, it uses an arbitrarily-chosen port up in the ~50000 range.) RE: "on hold" - That will be removed after your question receives the required number of "reopen" votes from other Stack Overflow users.

Comment: @GordThompson Thanks for the advice, will re edit again..

Answer (score 0):

Try this connection string, also suggested by @ElliotFrisch.

```
java.sql.Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
     "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;" + "databaseName=PROWAPPS_DATA;"+"user=tiger;password=wood");
```

Reference:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428%28v=sql.110%29.aspx